# Python File Execute Acts Differently than Normal Explorer Execution or CMD

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I'm writing what should have been a very simple UAC Bypass application in python. After research and analysis, there is an identical DLL Search-order hijacking vulnerability present in Windows 7, 8, and 8.1.

First, forget all of the preparation. For example, I have, stored locally, a .cab file with a .dll inside that will launch cmd.exe. The point of this was to write it to a TEMP directory, use WUSA to extract it to the destination folder, and then execute the vulnerable application.

The reason I say forget the preparation is because it hasn't even made it into my list of problems yet. Say the destination program is "program.exe". When I double-click "program.exe," it spawns the CMD like it should. Also, when I open CMD and type "program.exe", the same things happens and I get the cmd.exe shell from the hijacked DLL.

However, onto my issue. Even when I do nothing but:

```
import os
os.sytem("program.exe") #Same thing with subprocess.call and Popen
```

I get the ORIGINAL program, NOT the hijacked one. This is very strange because it works correcty when I just double click or execute it through a normal CMD.

Is there something I'm missing? Why would this work in other scenarios but not with python?
[image]
As you can see, same security contexts... One executes with the hijacked DLL and the other launches the normal program. Why?

Comment: I see you're using 32-bit Python. Maybe it's related to WOW64. What happens when you start your program from `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`?